# Configurable product line items have $0.00 price and subtotal in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a configurable product in magento following this tutorial: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product
However when I add this product to an order through the admin panel the price of the item is zero seen here:
[image]

This is my product in magento:
[image]

Any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial doesn't seem to mention indexes. Did you do a reindex of at the very least the price index? Are your indexes set to manual?

Comment: I flushed all caches and reindexed the prices.